# Isn't index over an ordered column useless?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, indexing, types

I have an `sqlite` database with column called `openTime` of `BIGINT` type. I only search the database against this column (never others).

The database is slow in search, until I create an index over `openTime`. My question is: if the column is already in a neat simple format like `1608872700000` with constant stepsize, why is it expensive to search against it? I feel I am not being efficient by adding several gigabytes worth of index against something that is already an ordered integer. What trick am I missing here?

Comment: The database engine does not know that the stored data is already "ordered". Also note that even if you insert data sequentially it may not be stored "physically" in that order.

Comment: @SalmanA How can I inform it of this structure, in sqlite?

Comment: you can't the index should be sorted or if a hash you have a matrix, test different idex types, also it depends a lot on the query

Comment: @nbk the query is as simple as it gets. `select * where openTime < x and openTime > y`.

Comment: a table is by definition unsorted, an index depending on type is ordered, so your query will be faster with a index that sorts

Comment: I see. In this case, I think my question boils down to how to make a **clustered** index. Thus, I will have same database size with index and ZERO cost of extra size. I will experiment with it now.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot explicitly create a clustered index in SQLite. The only way is, if you define a table with the SQLite-specific `WITHOUT ROWID` clause, then that table's Primary Key will be clustered. This means that if your `openTime` is not suitable to be a PK (i.e. can have non-unique values) then you cannot have a clustered index on it

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in comments, it was too late to be efficient once the database is already built (in a random way that doesn't care about ordered insertion). At that point, the only way to inform it of the structure is to create an index, which incurs extra space.

I re-created the database from scratch with declaration of `NO ROWID`and specifying `openTime` as primary key, thus, the data is written in the ordered way right from the start. This is effectively a clustered index with zero space cost.